# is there a trivial equation for the sum of $m^0,m^1 m^2.....m^h$

Tags: analysis

Is there a similar trivial equation for solving $\sum^h_{k=0}(m^k)$ like for solving $\sum^h_{k=0}(k) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ as I want to evaluate the smallest h which when used will fulfill the equation $n \leq \sum^h_{k=0}(m^k)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum $1+m+m^2+\cdots+m^h$ is a finite geometric series. It has (for $m\ne 1$) the sum 
$$\frac{m^{h+1}-1}{m-1}.$$

However, for your application, this is not directly useful, and estimates will be necessary. The strategy depends on the sizes of the numbers involved.