# What is answer of $\sum_{i=m}^{n} a^i=?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How can i solve the $\sum_{i=m}^{n} a^i=?$, I thought this formula was like this $\sum_{i=m}^{n} a^i=a^m\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}$ but it's not true!

Comment: $$\sum _{i=m}^n a^i=\frac{a^{n+1}-a^m}{a-1};\;a\ne 1$$
$$\sum _{i=m}^n a^i=-m+n+1;\;a=1$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a trivial equation for the sum of $m^0,m^1 m^2.....m^h$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237217/is-there-a-trivial-equation-for-the-sum-of-m0-m1-m2-mh)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You counted the number of term wrongly. There are a total of $n-m+1$ terms.

Hence the formula should be $$a^m \cdot \frac{1-a^{n-m+1}}{1-a}$$

if $a \ne 1$.

You should handle the case where $a=1$ separately.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there:
$$\sum_{i=m}^na^i=a^m\sum_{i=0}^{n-m}a^i=a^m\frac{1-a^{n-m+1}}{1-a}$$
with the sum at $a=1$ being $n-m+1$, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to derive it without any confusion.

Let $S = a^m + a^{m+1} + \cdots + a^n$. Then we see that
$$
S = a^m + a(a^m + a^{m+1}+ \cdots + a^{n-1}) = a^m + a(S-a^n)
$$
Then by solving for $S$ you have a formula for $S$. Hope you can finish that.